# Windows 10 won't go to sleep

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, sleep, power

Recently, Windows started to hang when going to sleep, which then shuts down on its own. The odd thing is that this doesn't happen all the time. It is able to sleep normally without issues when I just boot up, but after a certain time it can't sleep.

The monitor turns off, which seems to indicate it gets past the graphics driver, but then something prevents it from turning off. The only externally connected devices I have connected are a USB, mouse, headphones and a Logitech gamepad.

This issue seems to have started after I did a slight rework of my components (moved the PSU, changed the fan configuration), but if it was a hardware issue (such as a loose cable, or a bad connection), it *should* be present at all times, so I wouldn't be able to go to sleep even if I just boot.

Is there a way I can log what Windows does as it goes to sleep?

EDIT:

I've done a bit of digging in the event viewer. When I put the PC to sleep, Windows begins to mess around with the system time for around 3 times before seemingly crashing.

So the first event is this:

```
The system time has changed to ‎2023‎-‎05‎-‎11T16:11:27.500000000Z from ‎2023‎-‎05‎-‎11T16:11:25.934263600Z.

Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.
Process: '' (PID 4).
```

The next event is this:

```
The time provider NtpClient is currently receiving valid time data from time.windows.com,0x9 (ntp.m|0x9|0.0.0.0:123->168.61.215.74:123).
```

The next event is:

```
The time zone information was refreshed with exit reason 0. Current time zone bias is 240.
```

The time is changed again, but only this time, there is a process:

```
The system time has changed to ‎2023‎-‎05‎-‎11T16:11:39.467687100Z from ‎2023‎-‎05‎-‎11T16:11:41.258892800Z.

Change Reason: An application or system component changed the time.
Process: '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\svchost.exe' (PID 20712).
```

The time is changed, synchronized with Windows' servers, the time zone is refreshed another 2 times before crashing.

Running **diskpart** followed by **list volume** yields the following list of volumes:

```
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D   Nexus        NTFS   Partition   1863 GB  Healthy    Pagefile
  Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition    464 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 2         Recovery     NTFS   Partition    529 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 3                      FAT32  Partition     99 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 4                      NTFS   Partition    584 MB  Healthy    Hidden
```

D:/ is an HDD connected via SATA port, and C:/ is my main boot drive. So according to the event viewer, some hidden "Volume 4" (which by the looks of the Disk Management program, is another recovery partition):

[image]

After turning on the PC after this crash, a dump file was created. WhoCrashed gives the following analysis:

[image]

I'm not sure if the time change has anything to do with my issue, but I tried to put my PC to sleep again just after it booted, and not only did it sleep properly, but the only time change that occurred was after I turned it on (which makes sense).

EDIT 2:

Luckily, Windows has a bluescreen after I put it to sleep. This means that I have a dump file that I can analyze.

After using WinDBG to analyze the dump file, I was given the following information (after running !analyze -v):

```
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffd50f008a22f0, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff8076c6f4850, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffd50f076f7de0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.Sec
    Value: 2

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on Desktop

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.Sec
    Value: 23

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 82

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.InsufficientDumpfileSize
    Value: 1


DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0xc
  Insufficient Dumpfile Size
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

BUGCHECK_CODE:  9f

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffd50f008a22f0

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff8076c6f4850

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffd50f076f7de0

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff8076b260000 pci

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff807`6c6f4818 fffff807`665637a7 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffd50f`008a22f0 fffff807`6c6f4850 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff807`6c6f4820 fffff807`665636c1 : ffffd50f`246a6d70 00000000`00000000 ffffd50f`1b4a41f0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xdf
fffff807`6c6f4890 fffff807`6628bbd2 : ffffd50f`246a6da8 fffff807`641c9180 fffff807`641c9180 00000000`00000002 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x31
fffff807`6c6f48e0 fffff807`6628ac4d : 00000000`00000000 fffff807`662d9485 00000000`00140001 00000000`000a5e26 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0x172
fffff807`6c6f49d0 fffff807`6640059e : 00000000`00000000 fffff807`641c9180 fffff807`66d27a00 ffffd50f`2112e440 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x5dd
fffff807`6c6f4c60 00000000`00000000 : fffff807`6c6f5000 fffff807`6c6ef000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x9e


IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.19041.2728

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_rt640x64_IMAGE_pci.sys

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {2ce71122-4407-ac30-726e-512dc09f0103}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

As per the dump output, the error code is 9F. I found this code on [Microsoft's list of error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x9f--driver-power-state-failure). Following the instructions written there, I can find the troubled driver using the command `!devstack ffffd50f008a22f0`, which gives this output:

```
0: kd> !devstack ffffd50f008a22f0
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffd50f050c8050  \Driver\rt640x64   ffffd50f050c81a0  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffd50f050c8020

> ffffd50f008a22f0  \Driver\pci        ffffd50f008a2440  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffd50f008a2c30 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_E0001458&REV_0C\01000000684CE00000"
  ServiceName is "rt640x64"
```

Decoding the `DeviceInst` value gives a vendor ID of 10EC and a device ID of 8168. Looking it up on [PCILookup](https://www.pcilookup.com/?ven=10ec&dev=8168&action=submit) tells me that the problematic device is the Realtek PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

So now the question is *why* it's preventing my PC from sleep. I will currently try the following:

1. Disable it. I don't use the Ethernet port anyways, but I'd rather fix it because I do plan on using it in the future.
2. Update the PCIe driver (maybe it's corrupt?)

I will start with the simpler option of disabling it in the control panel to possibly see if it's actually the cause of the problem, rather than a symptom.

EDIT 3:

Seems like it's a symptom. I disabled the Realtek PCIe Ethernet adapter in control panel, and the same thing occurred. The only difference was that it flat out refused to crash. So the monitor turned off, but all the fans kept spinning. It was only after I pulled my mouse and keyboard out of the rear mobo IO panel did it suddenly shut off.

WinDBG still shows that it's the same error (0x9F) and the 0x3 parameter, but now it's my Nvidia GPU that's the problem.

This looks to me like a PCIe issue overall. The **PCIe** Ethernet, the rear panel USB, and the GPU are all connected via PCIe one way or another. I had the "PCIe Link State Power Management" setting in the Power Options set to Off, but I will try to set it to "Moderate Power Savings" to see if that has any effect.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: [Create energy report](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-energy-report/) with the command `powercfg /energy` and post the result file (not an image) online (OneDrive, dropbox etc).

Comment: Given that the device starts to go to sleep (even graphics turns off) I doubt that it's a device/thing preventing it from going to sleep the right way (which would show up in such report)

Comment: If you use Sysinternals' PsShutdown, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown,  to make the PC sleep, does that work?

Comment: @harrymc While I agree with Yisroel, I still made a link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eWLcH4NtseDNEHmaGhTdEDHG0sBOWoMm/view?usp=share_link just in case it can help

Comment: You need to set the link as private. (I don't know if the problem will show up in the report, but better check it).

Comment: As another test that will close off more directions, you may test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). If nothing comes up in this and in the report, then this is possibly a hardware problem.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik As of now, it works, but I just had to reboot my PC since the issue happened even with hibernate. I will let you know a bit later after Windows has had time to screw itself up.

Comment: @harrymc You should have to request access.

Comment: Also, after running Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth, sfc /scannow reported corrupt files. I will let you know if that helped.

Comment: If there were corrupt files - [Do a Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). This is the same as a major Windows upgrade (even of the same version to itself), so take the same precautions.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Nope, just tried it and it didn't go to sleep. I'm not willing to do a full refresh of Windows because it's a hassle to get everything back up and running again. Gotta love Windows slowly killing itself for no reason whatsoever. I also did a Windows update recently, shouldn't that have helped somehow?

Comment: It should be *relatively safe* to reinstall Windows, *keeping files (and applications)*. 1. Make a full disk image, in case something *does* go wrong. 2. Download and burn the ISO, using the MS media creation tool. 3. Reinstall, keeping files  https://www.itpro.com/operating-systems/microsoft-windows/358036/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-without-losing-data . This can be as fast as SFC/DISM repair. (@explodingfilms101, Agreed, MS is monetizing Windows at the expense of users. Since many PC's on which I work don't meet Win 11 requirements, it will be Ubuntu full-time after Win 10 EOL.)

Comment: @harrymc Nope, didn't work. I did the Repair Install and it still doesn't go to sleep.

Comment: I would like to see the report of [powercfg /energy](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-energy-report/).

Comment: @harrymc Here is the Google Drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ocJQ7iNeHH2PYilizUQS1QP1s0z9ZbDq/view?usp=sharing Just request access

Comment: I prefer not requesting access, please make it public.

Comment: @harrymc There's nothing there that is out of the ordinary. I updated the original question with some more info I've found.

Comment: @harrymc Have you taken a look at the edits?

Comment: Yes, which is why I would prefer having a look at the energy report *and* the `.dmp` file.

Comment: @harrymc See edits.